# NSUserDefaults being wiped between views

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am setting an NSUserDefaults value when a button is pressed, however when the view is transitioned the value is unset, and returns as nothing. 
Code:
BUTTON CODE

```
func chooseFriend(sender: UIButton) {
        let requestIndex = sender.tag
        let friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(friendChosen, forKey: "usernameToMessageWith")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        print(">>\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("usernameToMessageWith")! as String)")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toChat", sender: self)
    }
```

NEXT VIEW CODE

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("TRANSITIONED")
        let receivedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("usernameToMessageWith")! as String
        print("RECEIVED USERNAME:\(receivedUsername)")
        refreshTable()
        let swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        testLabel.text = ""
        self.messages.addObject("Loading......")
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
TRANSITIONED
RECEIVED USERNAME:
```

Comment: What message is printed in `chooseFriend`?

Comment: Are you sure `friendChosen` is not nil at the time of settings it?

Comment: Try using `valueForKey("usernameToMessageWith") as? String` instead of `stringForKey("...")` and save your data using `setValue(value, forKey: "")`

Comment: @nickpitoniak stringForKey returns an optional string. use if let to unwrap the optional or use nil coalescing operator ?? "" to return an empty string or a default value in case of no value (nil)

Comment: dont u call chooseFriend after viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is that a problem? This code has worked well for me, but all of a sudden crashed today and stopped sending the NSUserDefaults properly

Comment: @NickPitoniak can you show crash, I think have problem with your friendlist. Some error data in there

Comment: @vienvu the crash is on the second view controller because it is not able to access the information that should be provided with NSUserDefaults. I just asked a new question and elaborated on my problem. If you get some extra time, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with your code and don't see problem with `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Vien", forKey: "usernameToMessageWith")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

and:

```
let receivedUsername = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("usernameToMessageWith")! as String
    print("RECEIVED USERNAME:\(receivedUsername)")
```

and log:

```
RECEIVED USERNAME:Vien
```

So I think that problem in your `chooseFriend`. You should check this line code:

```
let friendChosen = self.friends.objectAtIndex(requestIndex) as! String
```

Comment: chooseFriend is working properly, and I am able to call the NSUserDefault right after setting it. Can you think of another reason it may not work?